# NPM global package: How to store data?

Tags: javascript, npm

I am maintaining a global npm package, the package is an CLI

[image]

What i want to do is, for example when the user choose 'Iphone 11' option, the next time user run the package again, 'iPhone 11' should be on top, and from that I think I need to save data to do this

Should I doing this by writing using file system module? and where to save that? or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by writing file using fs-extra and save it to __dirname + '/some-file.json'

when I need to read it again, just using require(__dirname + '/some-file.json')

Answer (score 0):

there are few way, i would recommend to store the configuration in a file that has a common format (json, yaml, etc.) in appropriate path, such as `$HOME/.my-pkg.json`, `~/.my-pkg/conf.json`, `$HOME/.cache/my-pkg/`, etc.